# Objective-C valueForKey int returning incorrect value

Tags: objective-c

So I'm currently working on an Objective-C project, and I'm calling `[mySpecialObject valueForKey:@"myVariable"]`, which is supposed to return the value 3 (an integer).

Going through the debugger, the object's value at the key is in fact 3, but calling `[mySpecialObject valueForKey:@"myVariable"]` returns 807.

Typecasting `(id)[mySpecialObject valueForKey:@"myVariable"]` returns `(__NSCFNumber *)0x0000000000000327 (int)3`

Does anyone know what's causing this mismatch? Am I typecasting incorrectly?

Formatted:

```
[mySpecialObject valueForKey:@"myVariable"] // SHOULD RETURN 3
(int)[mySpecialObject valueForKey:@"myVariable"] // returns 807
(id)[mySpecialObject valueForKey:@"myVariable"] // returns (__NSCFNumber *)0x0000000000000327 (int)3
```

NOTE: To be clear, myVariable is of type int inside mySpecialObject, and I am casting the return value to int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `valueForKey:` method returns an `id`, it must *wrap* all primitives into Objective-C objects. In this case, `int` is wrapped in `NSNumber` object.

If you know that the field/property is of type `int`, do this:

```
int num = [[mySpecialObject valueForKey:@"myVariable"] intValue];
```

Reference documentation: [Scalar and Structure Support in Key Value Coding](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/DataTypes.html)